# PayPal Smart Button INVALID_RESOURCE_ID

Tags: javascript, c#, paypal

I'm trying to integrate the PayPal payment on my website by using the [SmartButtons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/) by creating the order in the [server side](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/#).

After following the steps from the docs like by initializing the buttons then by setting the server side code to create the orderID when i try to make a payment i get on the client side the following error:

```
Error: INVALID_RESOURCE_ID↵    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.label=paypal&style.layout=horizontal&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&style.height=52&components.0=buttons&locale.country...
```

The orderID that is received on the client side is the right one as it's the same created on the paypal dashboard.. after reading some other similar questions someone was saying to capture the payment `onApprove` but even after setting the API to capture the payment the request just doesn't get inside the api to capture the payment.

My buttons code looks like this:

```
var PAYPAL_SCRIPT = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=XXXXXX&currency=EUR';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', PAYPAL_SCRIPT);
script.onload = function(){
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            shape: 'rect',
            color: 'gold',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            label: 'paypal',
            tagline: false,
            height: 52
        },
        createOrder: function() {
            return fetch('https://localhost:44350/payment/paypal/order/create/', {
              method: 'post',
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
              }
            }).then(function(res) {
              return res.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
              return data.headers[2].Value[0]; // Use the same key name for order ID on the client and server
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return fetch('https://localhost:44350/payment/paypal/' + data.headers[2].Value[0] + '/capture/', {
            method: 'post'
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(details) {
            // Show a success message to the buyer
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
        });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
}
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Then my api controllers are the following:

```
    [HttpPost("paypal/order/create/")]
    public Task<HttpResponse> PayPal()
    {
        
        return PaypalHelper.CreateOrder("XXXXX", "XXXXXX", true);
    }

    [HttpPost("paypal/{orderID}/capture/")]
    public Task<HttpResponse> PayPal(string orderID)
    {

        return PaypalHelper.CaptureOrder(orderID, "XXXXX", "XXXXX", true);
    }
```

Where the method to create the order looks like this:

```
 public async static Task<HttpResponse> CreateOrder(string publickey, string privatekey, bool debug = false)
        {
            var request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
            request.Prefer("return=representation");
            request.RequestBody(BuildRequestBody());
            //3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
            var response = await PayPalClient.client(publickey, privatekey).Execute(request);

            if (debug)
            {
                var result = response.Result<Order>();
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status);
                Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", result.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", result.CheckoutPaymentIntent);
                Console.WriteLine("Links:");
                foreach (LinkDescription link in result.Links)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
                }
                AmountWithBreakdown amount = result.PurchaseUnits[0].AmountWithBreakdown;
                Console.WriteLine("Total Amount: {0} {1}", amount.CurrencyCode, amount.Value);
            }

            return response;
        }

        private static OrderRequest BuildRequestBody()
        {
            var order = new OrderRequest()
            {
                CheckoutPaymentIntent = "CAPTURE",
                PurchaseUnits = new List<PurchaseUnitRequest>()
                {
                    new PurchaseUnitRequest()
                    {
                        AmountWithBreakdown = new AmountWithBreakdown()
                        {
                            CurrencyCode = "EUR",
                            Value = "100.00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                ApplicationContext = new ApplicationContext()
                {
                    ReturnUrl = "https://www.example.it/vmenu?paypal=success",
                    CancelUrl = "https://www.example.com?paypal=error"
                }
            };

            return order;
        }
```

The data in the createOrder fetch is the following:

```
{headers: Array(3), statusCode: 201}headers: Array(3)0: {Key: "Cache-Control", Value: Array(1)}1: {Key: "Date", Value: Array(1)}2: Key: "Paypal-Debug-Id"Value: ["97fcfafaae8ef"]__proto__: Objectlength: 3__proto__: Array(0)statusCode: 201__proto__: Object
menu_test.js:33
```

While by getting `data.headers[2].Value[0]` the result is 97fcfafaae8ef

Comment: Provide some sample data. What has the client received from the server. What is an example order ID. Print it all to the console.

Comment: @PrestonPHX here is the screen from the console log https://gyazo.com/23f42b73a3c07b8e2e933d7a1246bdd2 and even updated the question with the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the wrong ID. A PayPal-Debug-Id is not an orderID.

Also, orderIDs are not returned in the header, they are returned in the body, as 'id'.

You can see a Sample Response here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create

Comment: I actually had to return `var result = response.Result<Order>();` instead of response as it's the Result that has the valid id as you said